# How to make a usb auto run in Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: linux

I get what everyone is saying and suggesting, but I just got a EEE PC 2G surf as a gift for my son.  I can find my way around Windows, but Linux/Ubuntu is unknown territory.  All I want to do is to load Windows XP on the EEE with a bootable USB or scan drive disc, but no one is able to tell me step by step how to do this. My son (7) only works on Windows XP at his school.

Can some please explain without getting too technical?

I already made a bootable usb, when i insert it into the eee it says open program with file manager/photo manager or mediaplayer.  If I say file manager it opens up a console that says something like right ..... conflict, and then asks me to open if up again with something else.

Comment: The title and question body don't seem to be linked to each other. Are you trying to use USB to install Windows XP *to* the EEE instead of the OS that's already on it?

Comment: Yes Journeyman Geek I have loaded xp on a bootable usb and want to install it on the eee.

Comment: using what method, and what problems are you facing? Edit these into your question

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you made the XP installer USB correctly, you need to reboot, and select the USB key as your boot device. This is either through the BIOS (by setting the USB key as the first boot device) or by pressing a button at the BIOS screen to select the boot device. You cannot run the XP installer from ubuntu.

You can enter the BIOS by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> when the Asus logo appears upon reboot.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a bootable USB of a Windows ISO file using the unetbootin application on Linux.

Comment: Thank you blogger I already made a bootable usb what is unetbootin application - where do i look for this on the eee.